# @microsoft/fetchEventSource dispose method always curRequestController.abort with console error log

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

[console error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItWmG.png) [source code step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ0h2.png)   [source code step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWo8.png)

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation was aborted.
this message always show, even the request is finish success.
how to hidden this log or has other solution ??
i searched github issue, but found no solution, is anyone face the same issue ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: preview image not show,  i update the three images